# Can i use HtmlUnit to listen for resource loading events?

Tags: java, loading, htmlunit, headless-browser

I'm trying to use HtmlUnit to detect resources (scripts, images, stylesheets, etc) that fail to load on a webpage.

I've tried

```
new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {
    @Override
    public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
        WebResponse response;
        response = super.getResponse(request);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        return response;
    }
};
```

to no avail. It doesn't seem to handle CSS, images or JS, despite HtmlUnit logging:

> statusCode=[404] contentType=[text/html] 
>   File: /resources/style.css

For reference, here's the file I'm loading:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("get", "someBadLink", true);
            xhr.send();
        </script>
        <link href="/resources/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="bad_image.png">
    Cool.
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to use HtmlUnit to detect the AJAX resource, CSS script and image that all 404?

Answer (score 1):

- For AJAX, you have to wait as hinted [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#AJAXDoesNotWork).
- HtmlUnit doesn't automatically loads [HtmlLink](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlLink.html#getWebResponse(boolean)) and [HtmlImage](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlImage.html#getImageReader()), for performance reasons.
- Please find below snippet that will print all. You can use [.getByXPath()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getByXPath(java.lang.String)) to get list of all elements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {

        new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {
            @Override
            public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
              WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
              System.out.println(request.getUrl());
              System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
              return response;
            }
        };

        String url = "http://localhost/test.html";
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

        // to wait for AJAX
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(3000);

        // to forcibly load the link
        HtmlLink link = page.getFirstByXPath("//link");
        link.getWebResponse(true);

        // to forcibly load the image
        HtmlImage image = page.getFirstByXPath("//img");
        image.getImageReader();
    }
}
```