# Get resources of a page using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, html-parsing, htmlunit

How do I get the "absolute URL" and the "File" of all resources that a page loads?

When I have a HtmlPage object in the variable `page`, `page.save(new File(path));` saves the resources. If I save the resources like this I just have the files but not the corresponding URLs.

Comment: Could solve it with the help of:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31261340/3634099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the help of:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31261340/3634099

```
@Override
public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
 WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
 request.getUrl()
 request.getUrl().getPath();
 request.getUrl().getFile();
 return response;
}
```